# Multirow column with css flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a grid of 5 boxes (divs) where the first one has a portrait layout, and the rest have half the height of the first one (screenshot below)
[image]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 portrait"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

It would have been easy using float:left and display block, but i'm using bootstrap 4 which uses flexbox so no support for float left and i can't get it to work as expected. Is there a way to do this even with flexbox ?

PS: the row div has flex-wrap: wrap;

Comment: Although there are other solutions, you can use two grids - the top one with two columns and the second one with two rows and two columns.

Comment: this would complicate my php as this should be rendered with a PHP loop. and the will be more rows and columns..

Comment: Its almost similar: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/272327/

Comment: @Badr use PHP or JS to group your collection into sub-collections and place your loops individually inside of the nested rows. That is the recommended html structure with flex.

Comment: Thank you all. @PatrikValkovič the code in your jsfiddle is the closest to what i need, so i will use it (y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  
}

.col-md-4 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: green;
}

.portrait {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: blue;
 }

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 portrait"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 red"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 red"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this only works with a **fixed height** for the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to achieve the results displayed in your image.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 portrait">PUT YOUR PORTRAIT CONTENT HERE</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">TOP LEFT AFTER PORTRAIT</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">TOP RIGHT AFTER PORTRAIT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">BOTTOM LEFT AFTER PORTRAIT</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">BOTTOM RIGHT AFTER PORTRAIT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is done by creating  a new row, inside of a col, which is itself inside of another row.